# Test for change over time in a time series

Tags: time-series, t-test

I have a [time series of anomalies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTbMn.png) in some data, with 69 observations in total. I want to statistically test if the number of anomalies in the time series have increased over time? Can I use a t-test for the purpose, possibly by dividing my data into 2 or 3 groups, and then comparing these groups? In case, I'm completely off, please suggest a better test/approach. Statistics, unfortunately, isn't my strong suit.

Comment: I think time series analysis is a little more complex than the usual "test for different samples". This is because there may be some underlying time-dependant structure on your data, and therefore distributional assumptions are hardly met in time series.

Given that as a fact, the first approach that comes to my mind would be to fit one of the various kind of time series models (see, e.g., http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/R_time_series_quick_fix.htm for a quick tutorial in R) along with a straight line and see if the slope of that line is significant or not.

Comment: The fit can be checked by substracting the fitted line and perfoming an analysis to the autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation functions of the residuals, and see if they match the model you initially guessed. This is the most basic idea that comes to my mind at present.

In any case, I would recommend you to check some books on Time Series Analysis (the book of Brockwell and Davis is the introductory text used in most time series courses. Search for "Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting").

Answer (score 3):

"Increasing over time" kind of implies a smooth increase. Splitting the time series would actually be testing for the difference in the number of anomalies in the two periods. That's valid, but if you're looking for a smooth increase, you might be better off just doing a simple linear fit, and then calculating the confidence intervals on the trend. If there's a possible constant trend (horizontal line across your data that fits within the confidence intervals), then it's likely that there's no statistically significant change.

From glancing at your graph, It's difficult to tell if that's the case, but if you want some quick R code, try this (replace `AirPassengers` with your data, assumes your data is in the `ts` format):

```
AP.fit <- lm(AirPassengers ~ time(AirPassengers))
AP.ci <- predict(fit, interval="confidence")
plot(AirPassengers)
abline(AP.fit, col='red')
lines(x=as.vector(time(AirPassengers)), y=as.vector(AP.ci[,3]), col='red', lty=2)
lines(x=as.vector(time(AirPassengers)), y=as.vector(AP.ci[,2]), col='red', lty=2)
```

Which gives you something like:
[image]